# Apportable Protocol Declaration not found

Tags: android, objective-c, ios7.1, apportable

Error in apportable:

```
../ScanGiftViewController.m:21:38: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate'
@interface ScanGiftViewController ()<AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate>
```

Am I forgetting something?
deps and headers look like this:

```
"deps": [
      "AVFoundation",
      "FacebooSDK",
      ],

"header_paths": [
      "..",
      "./Frameworks/AVFoundation",
      "./Frameworks"
      ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate is not yet declared or implemented in Apportable. For now, you'll need to find a workaround for your app that doesn't use it.

Comment: is there a timeframe for it to be included?

Comment: There is no timeframe yet. Create an issue at https://code.google.com/p/apportable/issues/list to track and allow others to Star it to increase the priority

Answer (score 0):

Please check did you include `AVFoundation` framework to the project and imported it to your class as below

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```